# Convergence using Matlab ODE solvers

Tags: matlab, ode

Hi I'm solving an initial value ODE problem and would like to be able to plot the convergence. I've checked in the documentation and found that at each timestep the error is calculated but I can find no way to return this value.
Does anyone have any ideas, perhaps by playing around with output functions (from odeset).
Thanks

Comment: Which function are you calling to solve your problem?

Comment: the error values can be found if you open the ode45 file. I don't know if you can find a specific function to do that

Answer (score 0):

I was looking here to find the answer myself.
This closest I found is to vary the initial step size & max step size of ode45 using [odeset function](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/odeset.html#f92-1039598)
Ideally, we want to set **min** step size to test convergence but that isn't provided here.